# How to execute Sync TFS Dynamics AX 2012 by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I would like to execute the AX 2012 TFS syncronization by Power Shell command.

By *TFS* I'm meaning *Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (TFS)*.

[image]

If I try to execute this command:

```
$AXC = '\\MyPath\MyAXC.axc'
$models = @("MyModel")
Sync-TFS -AXC $AXC -Models $models
```

The command open the client, still freeze try to sync but unfortunately nothing happens (not sync the code)

I didn't get any error messages.
I tried to clean the Usagedata (in temp folder too), removed and added the sysADM role.

There is any way to fix the issue? Or exist another command to execute the TFS Sync by Power Shell?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Where does the command `Sync-TFS` come from??? I don't think it's possible out of the box to do what you want, but you can create a startup command by modifying/extending `\Classes\SysStartupCmd` and then you would call `Ax32.exe` with command line arguments, which would trigger your custom `X++` code to synchronize.